# What method is used in Google's correlate?

Tags: time-series, correlation

Here is a recent Google correlate query:
http://www.google.com/trends/correlate/search?e=internet+usage&t=weekly#

As you can see in the search box at that link, I entered "internet usage" and Google did the rest. It shows a value of 0.9298 as the "correlation" with the query "data mining".   However, when I read **[page 2 of the Google white paper [PDF]](http://www.google.com/trends/correlate/whitepaper.pdf)**, it says:

> ```
> The objective of Google Correlate is to surface the queries in
> the database whose spatial or temporal pattern is most highly correlated
> with a target pattern. Google Correlate employs a novel approximate nearest
> neighbor (ANN) algorithm over millions of candidate queries in an online
> search tree to produce results similar to the batch-based approach employed
> by Google Flu Trends but in a fraction of a second. For additional details,
> please see the Methods section below....
> ```

So, my question is:
Is Google using a normal Pearson or Spearman correlation to find this stuff or are they using something else? If so, can you explain the general technique?

==================

Also, notice in the plot that the search for "internet usage" (and "data mining") drops during the summer months and really dives around Christmas.  I would guess that kids and their homework have something to do with this.

Comment: Aren't these just Pearson correlation coefficients as reported on the [tutorial](http://correlate.googlelabs.com/tutorial/)? (Section *Correlated Queries*)

Comment: @chl: You're right.   I clicked on the FAQ's, but got sidetracked by the Whitepaper.   So, they're using correlation of a time series (not the change in the time series).    That's like calculating the correlation of a stock price, not returns.    That's a little surprising.

Comment: I also noticed that the data for the same query don't match on Google Trends and Correlate.   I sent Google an e-mail.

Comment: @chl: although your answer is a little obvious, it IS still an answer, and you should make it so, so it can be accepted.

Comment: @bill_080 Any response from google about why the data differ between the two systems? I actually found this question seeking an explanation related to your observation

Comment: @chandler : Google never answered the e-mail.   I played with both Trend and Correlate for a while, but neither were as useful as I expected, so I moved on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As chl points out, the [Google Correlate tutorial](http://www.google.com/trends/correlate/tutorial/) states that Google Correlate uses [Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient).

They don't mention which language this is implemented in, although [Google does use R](http://www.dataspora.com/2009/02/predictive-analytics-using-r/) for some applications, so I'd be guessing that.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of filling this thread. (I totally forgot about it, despite your ping :-)